# What does feeding the elders do in KittensGame?

Tags: kittens-game

I know that Leviathans unlock somewhat randomly, and I noticed that when I fed them that they were pleased and my necrocorns vanished. But what does it do? Can they be not pleased?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they can be "not pleased" and leave immediately. Feeding them takes away all your necrocorns, and at least as of today (July 5 2015), does nothing else.